# Base64 String HTTP Post

Tags: c#, php, ios, xamarin, http-post

This is my last two questions essentially merged into one. 
I'm building an app in Xamarin Studio for iOS using MonoTouch (C#) with a PHP HTTP Post backend.

On adding the feature to allow users to upload their own images I have the convert the image object to a Base64 string to save in PHP.

The process:
UIImage -> NSData -> byte[] -> Base64 String -> HTTP Post -> Decode Base64 string -> imagecreatefromstring -> imagejpeg to save in PHP


Here is the source I use in C#

```
public async void Post (string UID, string imageBase = null)
    {
        string data = "";
        if (imageBase != null) {
            data = string.Format ("METHOD=post&UID={0}&Image={1}", UID, imageBase);
        }

        HttpWebRequest r = await Info.createRequest (data);
        using (var resp = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse> (r.BeginGetResponse, r.EndGetResponse, null)) {
            return;
        }
    }

public static async Task<HttpWebRequest> createRequest (string json)
    {
        (new CancellationTokenSource ()).Dispose ();
        var request = WebRequest.Create (BaseUrl) as HttpWebRequest; 
        request.Method = "POST";    
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (json);
        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream> (request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, request)) {
            await stream.WriteAsync (postData, 0, postData.Length);
        }

        return request;
    }
```

Here is the source I use in PHP

```
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($_POST["Image"], TRUE)), "Users/Images/".$_POST["UID"]."/".md5(uniqid()).".png");
```

When I take the imageBase string from the C# code and manually paste it into the PHP code to replace $_POST["Image"], everything works fine. But it currently sends over a corrupted image stream, which I can only imagine is because the postData is encoded using UTF8, and when it's decoded on the server side, that I currently do not handle, it isn't decoded correctly. 

I was going to try to use a plain/text HTTP Post but that didn't seem to help, out of anything it mad it worse.

Comment: Where do you actually Base64Encode the string?

Comment: @alstonp `baseImage = this.image.AsJPEG (0.23f).GetBase64EncodedString (NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.SixtyFourCharacterLineLength);` the way it's encoded should be fine, after it encodes it, I copied the encoded string and pasted it into the actual PHP code rather than using $_POST["Image"] and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by using WebUtility.UrlEncode on the baseImage string.